# Laravel file permission error

Tags: php, apache, laravel, error-handling, laravel-4

I am getting an error even after setting permission to 777...

```
ls -al /var/www/html/supervisory/app/storage
total 32
drwxrwxrwx.  7    777 apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 .
drwxr-xr-x. 12 apache apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 ..
drwxrwxrwx.  2    777 apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 cache
-rwxrwxrwx.  1    777 apache   17 Apr 16 00:06 .gitignore
drwxrwxrwx.  2    777 apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 logs
drwxrwxrwx.  2    777 apache 4096 May 26 14:47 meta
drwxrwxrwx.  2    777 apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 sessions
drwxrwxrwx.  2    777 apache 4096 Apr 16 00:06 views
```

Iam getting an error on the homepage...

```
ErrorException

file_put_contents(/var/www/html/supervisory/app/storage/meta/services.json): failed      to     open stream: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you have the following settings

> 777 permission for app/storage folder

When you give 777 make sure you do it like this

```
chmod -R 777 app/storage
```

> 755 permission for folders
>
> 644 for files

If the error still there check for the ownership, the user is usually `www-data`

you can check it by creating a file 
 and type in the the following

```
<?php 
 echo shell_exec('whoami');
?>
```

after getting the user add the user like this

```
chown -R www-data:www-data
```

If the error is still there try to point your virtual host to public folder, I had had this issue for shared hosting.

Comment: thanks for your response.. after running this comnd `chown -R :www-data app/storage`IAM GETTING AN ERROR ... `chown: invalid group: ‘:www-data’ `

Comment: first check who is the user.. and then assign that user. If the user is xxx then the command is chown -R xxx:xxx

Comment: before that check if you have the file app/storage/meta/services.json, i dont think it is there

Comment: i found it ..its there...i have recreated project so now iam getting `Error in exception handler.` but the file is present...

Comment: so the permission issue is not solved? what exception do you get?

Comment: iam getting `Error in exception handler`  when i go to `localhost/myapp/public`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54423/discussion-between-harikrish-and-friend).

Comment: 777 permission is not needed, just `vendor` and `storage` dir permissions, and owned by `www-data`